# Corollary of Floquet Theorem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My course notes are located here
http://www.math.ualberta.ca/~mli/courses/current/524/chapter2.pdf

On page 18, in Corollary 2.24, I do not understand how
the line $y' = P^{-1}(AP - P'y)$ is obtained.

I was hoping someone might be able to explain how this was done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $x = Py$ then by the product rule ($P'$ denoting the matrix whose entries are the derivatives of the entries of $P$, and similarly for $y'$) one has
$$
x' = (Py)' = P' y + Py'
$$
and by simple substitution
$$
Ax = A(Py),
$$
so the statement $x' = Ax$ is equivalent to the statement $P'y + Py' = APy$.  If you subtract $P'y$ from both sides of this equation and then left multiply both sides of the resulting equation by $P^{-1}$ you see that $x' = Ax$ is indeed equivalent to the given equation $y' = P^{-1}(AP - P')y$.